# Sonar Related Issue-Which test covers which code(Integration Testing)

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube

In case I have multiple integration tests and all those tests cover some java class A.I wanted to know is there any way to which integration test covers which part of the java class A.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not yet possible. You can vote for the following ticket: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2501